# Order of configuration settings on JPA persistence xml file

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In this file, I have to place "class /class" above "jta-data-source /jta-data-source"; otherwise, it reports an XML error. Is this expected? Why does the order matter?

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="OrderManagement">

        <class>com.widgets.Customer</class>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyOrderDB</jta-data-source>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's expected.

The XML file must conform to an XML schema (available [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/index.html#2.1)), which defines that rule.

Comment: Thank you. Normally, that order doesn't matter. Not sure why they requires this.